# Java IO Permission Denied. but canWrite is true

Tags: java, desktop

I'm working on a small utility that is supposed to insert some files into a program directory. And when it comes to writing that file it failes with a
`java.io.FileNotFoundException (permission denied)`

This is my code (kind of messy, was debugging this alot)

```
while(ze!=null){

   String fileName = ze.getName();
      File newFile = new File(outputFolder + File.separator + fileName);

      System.out.println("file unzip : "+ newFile.getAbsoluteFile());

       //create all non exists folders
       //else you will hit FileNotFoundException for compressed folder
       new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();
       new File(newFile.getParent()).setWritable(true,false);
       if(newFile.isDirectory()){
           newFile.mkdir();
           newFile.getParentFile().setReadOnly();
           newFile.setReadable(true);
           newFile.setExecutable(true);
           if(newFile.setWritable(true)){
               System.out.println("permission set success");
           }else{
               System.out.println("permission set failed");
           }
           newFile.getParentFile().setReadable(true);
           newFile.getParentFile().setExecutable(true);
           newFile.getParentFile().setWritable(true);

           if(newFile.getParentFile().canWrite()){
               System.out.println("Parent Writable");
           }else{
               System.out.println("Parent Not Writable");
               newFile.getParentFile().setWritable(true, false);
           }
       }

       if(!newFile.canWrite()){
           System.out.println("We cannot write!");
       }else{
           System.out.println("We can write!");
       FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);             

       int len;
       while ((len = zis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len);
       }

       fos.close();   
       ze = zis.getNextEntry();

       }
}

   zis.closeEntry();
zis.close();

System.out.println("Done");
```

Output:
    file unzip : 
    permission set failed
    Parent Writable
    We can write!
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: (permission denied)

I tried both running the app in a CMD with admin rights and normal user (eclipse) and both fail, what can be the cause of this?

Comment: What's the path of `newFile` ? Are you able to navigate to that location using finder's "go to map" with that path (or similar on windows) ?

Comment: @HyperZ yes, I can go to the path without a problem.

Comment: What's going on here? If `newFile.isDirectory()` returns true, `newFile.mkdir()` must fail, and so must the eventual `new FileOutputStream(newFile)`. And what's al the messing around with the parent permissions? You're setting them read-only, then readable, then executable, then writable, ... NB `new File(newFile.getParent()).mkdirs();` is just a more complicated form of `newFile.getParent().mkdirs();`, and the same for the next line too. Don't write redundant code.

Comment: 'This is my code (kind of messy, was debugging this alot)'

Just debugging stuff. original didn't have anything with permissions and also didn't work.